# Justaudio Flutter cant run

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

```
onTap: () {
final player = AudioPlayer();
player.play(
player.setAudioSource('assets/sound.wav'),
);
```

There was an error in my just auido flutter so I can't run the audio. help me please.
I create my code in vscode and i had add asset in public yaml and import the package.

Comment: "There was an error" So post the error message, can't help without it.

Comment: @Wh1t3rabbit the argument type string cannot be assigned to the parameter type 'AudioSource'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[setAudioSource](https://pub.dev/documentation/just_audio/latest/just_audio/AudioPlayer/setAudioSource.html) expects to be passed an [AudioSource](https://pub.dev/documentation/just_audio/latest/just_audio/AudioSource-class.html). You are passing it a string.

Instead you can use [setAsset](https://pub.dev/documentation/just_audio/latest/just_audio/AudioPlayer/setAsset.html) with the string parameter, which will take care of creating the AudioSource and calling setAudioSource for you.

```
onTap: () {
    final player = AudioPlayer();
    player.setAsset('assets/sound.wav').then( () => {
        player.play();
    } ),
},
```

Please note that creating a new AudioPlayer instance on every tap is not a good idea, instead you should create the player just once and re-use it.

Comment: How about play audi without audio player, i just want to add sound on a button, when its clicked it sounded.